# How to set a variable from the selected text of a dropdown menu in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I am trying to set a variable from the value of a DropDown menu in Unity.

I wrote a script as follows, attached it to the dropdown and set it to run it in Unity under: **On Value Changed (Int32)**.

I have confirmed it is running when the dropdown changes from the debug output. However, it is giving me the `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when trying to get the dropdown's value.

The function I am running is `ChangeLocationDropDown()`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LocationSelectorDropDown : MonoBehaviour
{
public void ChangeLocationDropDown() {
        Debug.Log("DROP DOWN CHANGED");
        Dropdown m_Dropdown;
        m_Dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
        Debug.Log(m_Dropdown.options[m_Dropdown.value].text);
    }
}
```

I get the `DROP DOWN CHANGED` debug output but when I try to get the second debug it says:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object LocationSelectorDropDown.ChangeLocationDropDown ()`

[This Unity page](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206369473-NullReferenceException) suggests fixing this error by somehow using `GameObject.Find` to manually find the dropdown object first by its string name. But this is incredibly impractical and not a proper solution. I may need to make dozens of dropdowns. I need some simple clean way for each value to go into its own variable and/or update a database with their value with every change made.

What is the proper way to handle this?

ie. How do you update a string variable with the new text value of the DropDown?

Comment: Can you share screen shots of your scene hierarchy and the DropDown game object’s inspector? Your code should run if actually added as a component to your DropDown game object. If it’s a component of some other game object you’ll need to pass a reference to the DropDown component in your OnValueChanged delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried creating the same setup as you mentioned but I didn't got error.
Seems there might be any small mistake, please check below.
And also added the update to value to string variable part.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LocationSelectorDropDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Text textBox;

    string valueText = "";

    public void ChangeLocationDropDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("DROP DOWN CHANGED");
        Dropdown m_Dropdown;
        m_Dropdown = GetComponent();
        Debug.Log(m_Dropdown.options[m_Dropdown.value].text);


        //store in variable
        valueText = m_Dropdown.options[m_Dropdown.value].text;
        //set textbox value
        textBox.text = valueText;
    }
}
```

Also please have a look at the output [DropDownTest_Unity](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16hxgQI2P-fu8xNF9zyyA-5sQF79TFmeV/view?usp=sharing)

P.S. : I am putting it as answer as for the moment i cannot comment

Comment: Thank you very much Hiren! You were right it worked. My problem was I was using a "Text Mesh Pro" dropdown and didn't realize the code only would work for a regular dropdown. For TMPro Dropdown I needed: TMP_Dropdown m_TMP_Dropdown;
        m_TMP_Dropdown = gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_Dropdown>();
        Debug.Log(m_TMP_Dropdown.options[m_TMP_Dropdown.value].text);
 and that works. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your code as presented *will* work, provided it is added as a component to a gameobject that also contains a Dropdown component, like so:

[image: dropdown gameobject in inspector]

However, if the script responding to the valueChange event is a component of some other game object, you'll need to provide a reference. Here's a simple example script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DDDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Dropdown m_Dropdown; // wire this in Inspector



   public void OnMyDropdownChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log(m_Dropdown.options[m_Dropdown.value].text);
    }
}
```

Which will work if wired up in this manner (here the script is attached to the Controller game object):

[image: dropdown wiring]
[image: controller wiring]

Comment: Thank you very much Acme! You were right it worked. My problem was I was using a "Text Mesh Pro" dropdown and didn't realize the code only would work for a regular dropdown. For TMPro Dropdown I needed: TMP_Dropdown m_TMP_Dropdown;
        m_TMP_Dropdown = gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_Dropdown>();
        Debug.Log(m_TMP_Dropdown.options[m_TMP_Dropdown.value].text);
 and that works. Thanks again